# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous error in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, series

I currently have lots of 1000s in a column of my dataframe, I would like to change the value of this 1000 into a different number depending on whether the year given is before 2000 or after 2000
this is my code, my dataframe is called sales. year here is the current year obtained using datetime module

```
sales.loc[sales.remaining_lease==1000 & sales.lease_commence_date>=2000,'remaining_lease']=99-(year-sales.lease_commence_date)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71956180/20430449

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sales.loc[(sales.remaining_lease==1000) & (sales.lease_commence_date>=2000),'remaining_lease']=99-(year-sales.lease_commence_date)
```